# Drush does not acknowledge release of new core update

Tags: drush, updating

I am trying to update my drupal 7.31 core to 7.32 via Drush.

I ran the following commands

**$ drush pm-releases**

```
Project  Release  Date         Status                           
drupal   7.x-dev  2014-Oct-15  Development                      
drupal   7.32     2014-Oct-15  Supported, Recommended, Security 
drupal   7.31     2014-Aug-06  Security
```

After the above command i ran the following:

**$ drush pm-update drupal**

```
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 10/16/2014 - 07:33
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message 
 Drupal  7.31               7.31              Unknown 


No code updates available.
```

so i ran the following command:

**$ drush pm-update drupal-7.32**

```
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 10/16/2014 - 07:33
 Name         Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                     
 drupal-7.32  Unknown            Unknown           Specified version not found 


No code updates available.
```

Here are the versions for drush and composer. Both are to the latest versions.

$ drush version

```
 Drush Version   :  7.0-dev
```

Composer version 1.0-dev

Comment: Just for kicks, restart MySQL and then try. That worked for me with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution offered by Danny Englander worked.

Restarting mysql server did the trick.

Thanks Danny.

Answer (score 19):

`drush rf` 
will refresh the available releases and at that point you should be able to run 
`drush up` 
or 
`drush up drupal`.

Comment: Does not work ....

drupal         
Update information last refreshed: Thu, 10/16/2014 - 08:29
                      
 drupal  Unknown            Unknown           Specified project not found 


No code updates available.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Why on earth is this the last listed answer, with the highest upvotes, and the author has the highest reputation? Despite all these years using `drush` never heard of `pm-refresh` Works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. Can't get to update list of modules and core.  Tried CC, cache_update truncate. Well everything I could come up with and still nothing.
What is strange is that on localhost is where I get this, on remote server it is ok.

So I fixed it somehow with disabling and uninstaling update manager and installing it again.

Comment: Same problem, none of the solutions that I found online worked, except for this one :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all the great answers above, be sure to do a double check for possible [facepalm] brain-fail issues:

- are you logged in to the right server?
- the right drupal site path on that server?
- did you mess with your /etc/hosts file and forget?
- is www and non-www pointed to the same place?
- are you looking at a local or dev copy in your browser?

If you run `drush status` and it has the updated version but you still see the update alerts in the GUI Reports > Available Updates page then you might be a *total f#¢&ing idiot* like me and be looking at different copies of the site.

If you've already tried `drush rf` and you compare `drush status` and it has the same current version number you get when you run `drush pm-releases drupal` then you definitely have an issue other than drush not working properly.

Comment: Haha this was just me!

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem.

Restarting MySQL server didn't work for me.

Disabling update manager, uninstalling it and then re-enabling it worked for me.

```
$ drush -y dis update
$ drush -y pm-uninstall update
$ drush -y en update
```

Comment: Didnt I just said that above?

Comment: Yes, you did. Tried everybody's solution. Just wanted to let others know what worked for me. Luckily your solution worked for me.

Comment: @pachabhaiya's commands worked verbatim for me, when restarting MySQL didn't solve it, after running into this exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all execute:

```
drush pm-releases drupal
```

Then you should see all tag names like this:

```
 Project  Release  Date         Status                                      
  drupal   7.38     2015-Jun-17  Supported, Recommended, Security, Installed 
  drupal   7.x-dev  2015-Jun-17  Development
```

Now you can get Project name and Release number like this 'drupal-7.38' and execute this to force update to that release:

```
drush dl drupal-7.38
```

You can even choose a development version of update by write the development release number.

This also work with update modules. If you need to force update for a module like ctools for a dev release you can execute:

```
drush dl ctools-7.x-1.x-dev
```

Enjoy drush <3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the command

```
drush up drupal
```

was not finding the new drupal version. Even the update module, from the admin interface, was not showing the new drupal core release.
I've managed truncating the **cache_update** table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE  cache_update
```

For what I've seen, the update module caches the new release informations in this table, for some strange reasons the `drush cc all` command was not cleaning this table so the new drupal core release colund't be found.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here and no one suggested the simplest one which works every time for me:

```
drush cc drush
```

`drush cc all` clears all the Drupal caches, but does not clear the drush cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but I will share my recent experience regardless. For me, it was just a silly problem with drush not being able to access the internet (as I am behind a proxy).

The solution was to set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY (and their lower-case versions) env variables to the proper values.